# Show that the feasible region of a linear programming is a Polyhedron

Tags: solution-verification, linear-programming, polyhedra

Show that the feasible region of a linear programming is a Polyhedron.

---

My try:

I assume that the linear programming is of the following forms:

$$\text{min}/\text{max} \;\; z=\mathbf c \mathbf x  $$
$$\text{s.t.}\;\; \mathbf A\mathbf x =\mathbf b $$
$$\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0$$
$$$$

On the other hand by the definition every polyhedron is defined as a finite intersection of half-spaces, so denote by $M$ the polyhedron defined by the intersction of $m$ half-spaces, also every lower half-space $H^{-}=\{\mathbf x: \mathbf p^t \mathbf x \le \alpha\}$ can be written as
$$H^{-}=\{\mathbf x: \mathbf p^t \mathbf x \le \alpha\}=\{\mathbf x: -\mathbf p^t \mathbf x \ge -\alpha\}=H^{+}$$

From here we see that $$M=\bigcap_{i=1}^{m} H^{+}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{m}\{\mathbf x: \mathbf p_{i}^{t} \mathbf x \ge \alpha_i\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{m}\{\mathbf x: \mathbf p_{i}^{t} \mathbf x -\beta_i \mathbf x = \alpha_i\}$$
$$=\{\mathbf x: \mathbf p_{i}^{t} \mathbf x -\beta_i \mathbf x = \alpha_i , i\in \{1,...,m\}\}$$

$$=\{\mathbf x:\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf p_{1}^{t} -\beta_1 \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf p_{m}^{t} -\beta_m 
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf A}\mathbf x = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf \alpha_1\\
\vdots \\
\alpha_m 
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf b}\}$$

$$=\{\mathbf x:\mathbf A\mathbf x = \mathbf b\}\tag{I}$$

On the other hand the feasible region of the given linear programming is given by $$\{\mathbf x:\mathbf A\mathbf x = \mathbf b,\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0\}=\underbrace{\{\mathbf x:\mathbf A\mathbf x = \mathbf b\}}_{*} \cap \{\mathbf x:\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0\}$$

By $(\text{I})$, we know that $*$ is a polyhedron, so the feasible region is the intersection of a polyhedron with $ \{\mathbf x:\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0\}$, but is such intersection a polyhedron itself?

Comment: The feasible region is the intersection of the closed half spaces $(\mathbf {Ax})_i\ge \mathbf b_i$, $ (\mathbf {Ax})_i\le \mathbf b_i$, $\mathbf x_i\ge 0$

Comment: The right one is just the intersection of $n$ axis-parallel linear half-spaces. Alternatively, if you like matrix notation, it is just: $$\{x : Ix \geq 0\}$$

Answer (score 1):

if you understand how $Ax = b$ is polyhedron, then $x\geq0$ is just the non negative orthant, which you can easily visualize as intersection of half spaces. for instance is $x$ is in $R^2$, then $x\ge0$ means both it's components are positive. so, it is intersection of the half spaces $x_1 \geq 0$ and $x_2 \geq0$. to put it in matrix representation, $x\geq0$ means $Ix\ge b$ where $b$ is zero vector. so, you can write this as set of $m$ half space equations like you did. it is intersection of these $m$ halfspaces. $I_ix \ge 0$ for $i = 1, 2, ...m$, where $I_i$ is ith row of identity matrix.